# How to force single word spacing in section headings for two-column articles

Tags: spacing, formatting

I do not know how to force a single space between the words "Discussion" and "and" in the section heading below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}
\hyphenation{Conclusion}
\section{Discussion and Conclusion}
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\\` inside the section title. In that case you have to add the optional argument of the `\section` command to get the tableofcontents entry without linebreak.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section[Discussion and Conclusion]{Discussion and\\ Conclusion}
\end{document}
```

Another possibility is using of `\@startsection` to get the section title raggedright

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand\section{%
    \@startsection{section}{1}{0pt}{-1.2\baselineskip}{.2\baselineskip}%
      {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\raggedright}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Discussion and Conclusion}
\end{document}
```

Or you switch to the [`scrartcl`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) class

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\section{Discussion and Conclusion}
\end{document}
```